# WPF Out of memory error in a QR Code Scanner

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, aforge, zxing.net

I have attempted making a WPF QR Code Scanner Page using `AForge.Video.DirectShow` package to implement the video capture which uses an Image in the XAML side to display it.

The memory usage of the application increases rapidly and reaches 3.6GB+ in 15 seconds before crashing and throwing an out of memory exception at these lines of code:

```cs
private ImageSource BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
        IntPtr.Zero,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

The entire code of the WPF Scanner Page is:

```cs
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using ZXing;
using System.IO;

namespace QRCodeApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Scanner.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Scanner : Page
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
        private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
        public Scanner()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeCamera();
        }
        private void InitializeCamera()
        {
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            if (videoDevices.Count > 0)
            {
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
                videoSource.NewFrame += VideoSource_NewFrame;
                videoSource.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No video capture devices found.","No Camera");
            }
        }

        private void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        cameraImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(bitmap);
                    });

                    BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
                    Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(bitmap);

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        string downloadsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                        string initialDirectory = Path.Combine(downloadsPath, "QR Codes");

                        if (!Directory.Exists(initialDirectory))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(initialDirectory);
                        }

                        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        string fdt = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
                        string fileName = "QRCode " + fdt + ".png";

                        fileName = CleanFileName(fileName);

                        string path = Path.Combine(initialDirectory, fileName);
                        bitmap.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        videoSource.NewFrame -= VideoSource_NewFrame;
                        videoSource.SignalToStop();

                        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            {
                                cameraImage.Source = null;
                                videoSource = null;
                                videoDevices = null;
                                myframe.frame.Content = new Scanned(bitmap, path, false, false);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}", "An Exception occured");
            }
        }

        private ImageSource BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoSource != null && videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                videoSource.WaitForStop();
            }
        }

        private string CleanFileName(string fileName)
        {
            foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
            {
                fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '_');
            }
            return fileName;
        }



        private void Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myframe.frame.Content = new ScanSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `bitmap.Dispose()` when the scanning was done but it did not make a difference. Also stopped the camera and set the UI image source, video source and video devices to null. Keep in mind when the QR Code scans perfectly before app crashes the memory usage stop at just what it was before the scan got completed, so if memory usage was 1.5GB before QR Code scanned it will stop increasing and stay at 1.5GB while the app moves to the page I set.

Comment: `if memory usage was 1.5GB` and `The memory usage of the application increases rapidly and reaches 3.6GB+ in 15 seconds` means there are memory leaks. Perhaps the code is creating a lot of large buffers, inefficiently adding items to lists, splitting large strings, forgetting to dispose streams, bitmaps and other disposable objects. There are a lot of *bad* async calls too, like using `Task.Run` at the end to update the UI with `Dispatcher.Invoke`. The code itself creates multiple copies of the image but in the end, doesn't dispose the older images stored in `myframe.frame.Content` etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I feel like disposing older images should be a good starting point, but how exactly should I dispose older images? I tried bitmap.Dispose(); at the end of each frame which did not make a difference and cameraImage.Source = null; caused the video to flicker and not make any difference in memory. Also I'm quite amateur in WPF.

Comment: If those are big images then loading them into memory can of course be expensive. I assume you are processing captured images/video frames retrieved from a camera. Have you tried to reduce the resolution to create smaller images? If this is not possible then you should post-process the image to lower the resolution to lower the memory footprint of your application. A QR code scanner does not require high definition images.

Comment: While disposing the objects and also following the suggestions made by Panagiotis is really important, I don't believe that this is a memory leak. Unless you missed showing important code like a loop it doesn't make sense to mee that the allocated memory increases by 100% within a few seconds. It looks like it's directly related to the image you are processing.

Comment: You can download and install a memory profiler if you don't own Visual Studio Enterprise. Then profile your application to see what object(s) allocate that much memory. Right now it looks like your images are simply too big.

Comment: @BionicCode I will try lowering the resolution because its most likely 1080P but even a 1080P video playback wouldn't take anywhere near this much memory but I'm not able to get how exactly I'm supposed to dispose older images. Also I reduced the FPS and the time it takes to crash increased by 3 times.

Comment: @BionicCode I finally fixed the entire issue by using an external function from a DLL to delete the bitmap in BitmapToImageSource() and my app uses like only 200-400mb of memory now even with 1080P video capture.

Comment: Nice. Then how comes that the memory allocation rises up to ~4Gb within 15s? Your code doesn't imply that you were generating multiple image sources.

Comment: @BionicCode previously, out of memory error was being generated at BitmapToImageSource() function and after getting the Hbitmap from the bitmap, deleting it at the end of that function fixed the issue so that means the Hbitmap wasn't getting disposed before and it kept increasing as the app ran.

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage was being increased so much and so rapidly only because the older Bitmaps were not disposed and deleting hBitmap from BitmapToImageSource() every time entirely fixed the issue.

The Previous BitmapToImageSource() function:

```cs
private ImageSource BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
```

The updated BitmapToImageSource() function along with the external function to delete the bitmap which fixed the issue:

```cs
private ImageSource BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            try
            {
                return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

Comment: Note that this is a very poor implementation, especially for video. A much better implementation would be to use a `WriteableBitmap` (which is an image source) and upload the image pixel data into it as you receive them every frame.

Comment: @Blindy thanks for the suggestion, i will try to implement it in the way you suggested with WriteableBitmap but it would be great if I get to know how and why it is a poor implementation though.

Comment: It's very poor because you're copying from RAM to RAM once (`GetHbitmap()`) then you allocate a VRAM chunk of memory (`CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`), then copying from RAM to VRAM (same function as before). Whereas the `WriteableBitmap` way only copies from RAM to VRAM once, saving you a memory copy and a GPU allocation (and a CPU allocation for the `HBITMAP`).